# Replace character after a certain character/word but skip first match and also handle duplicates

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have to replace characters in URLs but only form a certain point and also handle duplicate characters.

The URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/001-one-two.html#/param-what-ever
http://example.com/002-one-two-three.html#/param-what--ever-
http://example.com/003-one-two-four.html#/param2-what-ever-
http://example.com/004-one-two-five.html#/param33-what--ever---here-
```

and they should look like this:

```
http://example.com/001-one-two.html#/param-what_ever
http://example.com/002-one-two-three.html#/param-what_ever_
http://example.com/003-one-two-four.html#/param2-what_ever_
http://example.com/004-one-two-five.html#/param33-what_ever_here_
```

In words replace `-` characters (any number of it) with a single `_` char but skip the first `-` after `#/`
The string length after the `#/` varies obviously and I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: strreplace with an array after finding `#/` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go, using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$in = array(
'http://example.com/001-one-two.html#/param-what-ever',
'http://example.com/002-one-two-three.html#/param-what--ever-',
'http://example.com/003-one-two-four.html#/param2-what-ever-',
'http://example.com/004-one-two-five.html#/param33-what--ever---here-'
);

foreach($in as $str) {
    $res = preg_replace_callback('~^.*?#/[^-]+-(.+)$~', function ($m) {
                return preg_replace('/-+/', '_', $m[1]);
            },
            $str);
    echo "$res\n";
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
~           : regex delimiter
  ^         : start of string
    .*?     : 0 or more any character, not greedy
    #/      : literally #/
    [^-]+   : 1 or more any character that is not a dash
    -       : a dash
    \K      : forget all we have seen until here
    (.+)    : group 1, contains avery thing after the first dash after #/
  $         : end of string
~           : regex delimiter
```

**Output:**

```
http://example.com/001-one-two.html#/param-what_ever
http://example.com/002-one-two-three.html#/param-what_ever_
http://example.com/003-one-two-four.html#/param2-what_ever_
http://example.com/004-one-two-five.html#/param33-what_ever_here_
```